# How to get a filtered list of files in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

I am trying to get a filtered (or patterned though I barely touch the pattern content) file list in a folder.

My initial approach was with `glob`:

```
list_files2 = os.listdir(accordingto)
movable = set()
n = 0
for f in list_files2:
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    name = name.rsplit("_", 1)[0]
    movable.add(name)
for m in movable:
    family = glob("{}{}*".format(dir, m))
    for f in family:
        # f is absolute path and needs to be relative
        shutil.move(f, target+f) # <- problem is here
        n += 1
```

which works *nearly as I expected* except for the fact that it returns an absolute path while I wanted a relative one (only the filename that is) to append it to the destination folder.

To make it more clear I have a folder with various images grouped in "families" which derive from the same original image. E.g.

- *family:* 71_157,23_850
- *images:* 71_157,23_850_1.jpg, 71_157,23_850_1.png, 71_157,23_850_3.jpg etc

I know I can process every item returned by `glob` but it seems a bit circular as approach.

My second approach was with `os.scandir`:

```
x = [f.name for f in os.scandir('images') if f.name.startswith(family in movable)]
```

which of course does not work at all though it works for a specific "family" of images e.g. for `51_332,-5_545` family

```
x = [f.name for f in os.scandir('images') if f.name.startswith('51_332,-5_545')]
```

and I could concatenate the results in a loop for example.

So, my question(s) are:

1. Is there a way to return a relative path with glob? Or I am stuck with absolute paths?
2. How can I get a filtered list of files with `os.scandir` in a "pythonic" manner?

Comment: `os.scandir`  part of python3 now, why not stick to it, if it works already?

Answer (score 1):

I use this handy little function.

```
import os, fnmatch
def List(Folder, Name):
    '''Function to get List of Files in a folder with a
       given filetype or filename'''
    try:
        string = '*' + Name + '*'
        FileList = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(Folder), string)
        return FileList
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error while listing %s files in %s : %s' % (string, Folder, str(e)))
        return []
```